# Como puedo instalar requests en python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-requests

Estoy intentando usar requests con python pero me sale el siguiente error una vez ejecuto el programa:

```
  File "cabeceras.py", line 4, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

En el archivo de python lo he importado con `import requests`

Ya he instalado el modulo con `pip install requests` e incluso he provado a crear un entorno en anaconda e instalarlo desde ahi pero sigue sin funcionar. Estoy utilizando windows.

Comment: Seguramente estás instalando en un intérprete o entorno distinto al que usas para ejecutar el script. Si haces `import sys; print(sys.executable)` en el mismo script que te da el error, obtendrás la ruta al intérprete que usas realmente. Lanza `pip` como módulo con `ruta/al/intérprete - m pip install requests`. Usar pip como script directamente siempre me ha parecido una mala idea, es fruto de muchas frustraciones especialmente en usuarios que empiezan con Python por no saber a que intérprete está asociado, "explícito mejor que implícito"

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [ModuleNotFoundError No puedo importar un módulo instalado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/404776/modulenotfounderror-no-puedo-importar-un-m%c3%b3dulo-instalado)

Answer (score 1):

a mi lo que me resulto fue instalar Python ajustando el path, en las variables de entorno y también ejecutar la orden

```
pip install requests
```

desde el cmd **no desde powershell** y después funcionó.

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas Pycharm ve a esta opción:

1. File - Settings - Project - Python Interpreter
2. Una vez allí buscas el icono "**+**"
3. En el buscador (lupa) digitas **request**
4. Seleccionas el resultado y finalmente das clic en el boton **Install Package**
5. Esperas que el proceso de instalación finalice y ya queda listo.

Probablemente en otro IDE sea similar